# Cannot access subdirectory subpages

Tags: htaccess, directory

I am working on a wordpress site for a client, who has a 2nd install in a subdirectory.
When I try to view a subpage on the 2nd install (domain.com/folder/subpage) I get the root directory install's 404 page.

It is not a htaccess issue because I have a similar set up on my own server where my website is in the root and I host other client websites in subdirectories, have never had a problem viewing any page in any sub-install.

Could it be that the hosting has got directory browsing disabled or another issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is the first WordPress installed in the root directory? If so, I would look to see if any of the mod_rewrite rules are preventing you from looking in the subdirectory where the second install is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed this errow after browsing for a couple of hours and trying many options.

In this block in your Apache httpd.conf file, 
(located in my CentOS instance at $ sudo vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf)

```
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride None
```

change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`.

Src: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/secondary-or-child-pages-returning-a-404-error-after-wp-34-update#post-3830892